# create a smooth animation with the hover effect, over an html element to convert this in a text

Tags: css

I've basically seen some answers where I can try to do something similar to what I need, but those examples are using text, about text. But in this case I need to achieve this with the  element, I would like that when I pass the cursor over, a smooth animation is produced and it becomes a text ("add text"). How can I do it?

```
<i class="fa fa-users red" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gp83bkuf/

Comment: checkout javascript's `innerHTML` `https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp`

Comment: you can use that with a `.hover()` to make it a hover effect to change the text inside

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @RamondeVries I need this with css.. only effect hover..

Comment: @yavg css can't change text or something like that, only the styling of the element

Comment: You need to use some `data-*` attributes and little tricky hacks to achieve that FX only by CSS. search for CSS only tooltip solutions. that fiddle is really *worthy* tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle the events in Javascript using Jquery for mouseenter and mouseleave in order to create you desired behavior. I have created an example using fadeIn fadeOut which renders a basic animation.

```js
  $('.myImage').mouseenter(function(){
      var $image =  $('.myImage');
 
      $('.myImage').fadeOut(2000,function(){
                $('.myText').fadeIn(2000);
        });
    });
 

$('.myText').mouseleave(function(){
      $('.myText').fadeOut(2000,function(){
                $('.myImage').fadeIn(2000);
        });
    })
```

```css
.myImage {
  font-size: 50px;
  color: red;
}

.myText
{
 font-size: 20px;
 color: red;
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<i class="myImage fa fa-users" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<p class="myText">add text</p>
```